# Propel case-sensitive phpNames for columns

Tags: php, mysql, propel

The relevant portion of my `schema.xml`:

```
<database name="Inventory" defaultIdMethod="native">
  <table name="Users" phpName="User">
    <column name="UserId" type="varchar" size="20" required="true" primaryKey="true" />
    <column name="FirstName" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
    <column name="LastName" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
    <column name="Password" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
    <column name="Salt" type="char" size="22" required="true" />
    <column name="RoleId" type="integer" required="true" />
    <column name="FailedLogins" type="integer" required="true" defaultValue="0" />
    <column name="LockedOut" type="boolean" required="true" defaultValue="false" />
    <column name="Active" type="boolean" required="true" defaultValue="true" />
  </table>
...
</database>
```

The following command fails with a `PropelException`:

```
UserQuery::create()
    ->filterByActive(true)
    ->update(array('FailedLogins' => 0, 'LockedOut' => false));
```

The error:

```
[Sat Nov 19 16:28:01 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.11] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PropelException' with message 'Cannot fetch ColumnMap for undefined column phpName: FailedLogins' in /home/andrew/pss-repository/vendor/propel/runtime/lib/map/TableMap.php:372\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/andrew/pss-repository/vendor/propel/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php(1668): TableMap->getColumnByPhpName('FailedLogins')\n#1 /home/andrew/pss-repository/vendor/propel/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php(1626): ModelCriteria->doUpdate(Array, Object(PropelPDO), false)\n#2 /home/andrew/pss-repository/login-reset-process.php(11): ModelCriteria->update(Array)\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /home/andrew/pss-repository/vendor/propel/runtime/lib/map/TableMap.php on line 372, referer: http://pss/login-reset-all.php
```

I am able to verify that the `FailedLogins` column is identified as `Failedlogins` in the Propel-generated code.  I realize that I can probably add `phpName` to the columns in question, but I was wondering if I have missed a configuration option.  I checked the [Propel buildtime configuration page](http://www.propelorm.org/reference/buildtime-configuration.html), and I see an option called `propel.samePhpName`, but as it is under the "Reverse Engineering" section it does not appear to be the option I need.  Others have asked [similar questions](http://osdir.com/ml/php.propel.devel/2005-05/msg00049.html), but I have not seen a clear answer.

Is there a configuration option to make the `phpName` of each column simply match the `name` attribute in the schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no way to do that, nor a build property.

Actually, you should not name your table attributes like you did, you should underscorize them:

```
<table name="Users" phpName="User">
  <column name="user_id" type="varchar" size="20" required="true" primaryKey="true" />
  <column name="first_name" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
  <column name="last_name" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
  <column name="password" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
  <column name="salt" type="char" size="22" required="true" />
  <column name="role_id" type="integer" required="true" />
  <column name="failed_logins" type="integer" required="true" defaultValue="0" />
  <column name="locked_out" type="boolean" required="true" defaultValue="false" />
  <column name="active" type="boolean" required="true" defaultValue="true" />
</table>
```

That way you'll get `UserId`, …, `FailedLogins`, …

William

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I needed to know.  I was aware of the automatic conversion to phpName that you describe when using underscores, but I'm used to using a PascalCase naming convention in databases.  If I get time, I'll see if I can submit a patch, but I don't know when that will be.